# Technology to accepts transparently tagged/untagged frames on an unconfigured AC port

Tags: vpls, evpn

Forehead: I come from the Enterprise world and I'm now approching SP world; I apologize in advance if I don't use the right terminology.

Hello,

I'm trying to think of a design where on the Attachment Circuit ports the distribution system, I keep it general/vague for now, can accept any type of untagged/tagged/link-local frame and forward it based on the MAC-address. I was proposed by a partner to go for EVPN-BGP implemented with Huawei but I then realized that on the AC port I can accept any type of frames but I have to know in advance which tagged frames to expect, so that I can bind the VLAN with the VNI. In fact this the relevant part of the configuration I don't want

```
[*Leaf1] interface 10ge 1/0/2.1 mode l2
[*Leaf1-10GE1/0/2.1] encapsulation dot1q vid 10
[*Leaf1-10GE1/0/2.1] bridge-domain 10
[*Leaf1-10GE1/0/2.1] quit
```

(above the subinterface with VlanID 10 is bond to the bridge domain)
https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000039339/6c964738/example-for-configuring-segment-vxlan-to-implement-layer-2-interworking-local-vni-mode

I know that with VPLS I can build virtual wires, where in any of them whatever frames that enters will be forwarded to the other end because there is no MAC learning process.

Hence:

1. EVPN-BGP limits me (at lest with Huawei) because on the AC port I must link VLANs with VNI but I then can forward frames based on the dest MAC address;
2. on VPLS, I need not think ahead of the tagged frames that might be carried by the virtual wire but the virtual wire itself carries the frames to one endpoint only.

So far I can deduct that if I need to forward frames to different endpoints I need two virtual wires **related to two different endpoints**; I know VPLS can make use of bridge-domains to aggregate virtual wires and allow to connect to one AC port to the bridge-domain but in the docs I have examinated so far there is no stress on how to configure the AC port.

Having studied a bit the overlay protocols I see that the VLAN information is not carried over the underlay as part of the frames, whereas I would like tagged frames to be carried by the overlay.

Goal: extend L2 domains across the overlay, hence I cannot make routing.

Question: can the VPLS-related AC port accept any kind of VLAN tag and forward it to the other overlay endpoints without configuring it in advance as done in the exceprt from the Huawei docs?

I'm aware of the following:

1. if behind two different destination ACs there is the same MAC address belonging (for whatever reason) to two different VLANs, a frame with such a destination MAC addres might be sent to all the destination ACs of interest and then might be discarded by the port of the other side of the dest AC ports if the trunk of the customer doesn't allow that VLAN tag;
2. what described in 1) might not be efficient but it would help the customer to change the VLANs allowed on trunk connected to AC ports on the fly **without the intervention of the Service Provider** that manages the overlay solutions.

As a last resource, a set of individual VPLS wires might be built, but I would like to be sure not to miss a flavor of VPLS, or other protocols, that might of help in my situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but can't you just use QinQ with customer ports and permit any C-tag?

Comment: We tested a solution purely based on QinQ (802.1ad) and it works, but in this way we cannot extend the solution over L3 hops, or maybe you mean that I can use QinQ on the AC port and link somehow the S-vlan with the bridge domain? I think I tried that on the S5700 series but I got an error by the OS. BTW I have never seen any Huawei doc documenting that solution.

Comment: As long as there's a contiguous L2 domain, QinQ should do what you (seem to) need. If you need to cross L3 hops then you require tunneling, sounds like VXLAN is a fit.

Comment: Yes, non problem with the overlay technology, the issue is with the AC ports. All the examples for the S5700 on the Huawei website show a mapping with incoming VLAN tags with VNI whereas I need to carry all the VLAN tags over the VNI. Since I haven't found examples among the Huawei's doc and I received some errors while trying to achieve my own goal, I thought it was no possible. Thanks a lot for your comments Zac67.